# QML IntValidator strange behavior for bottom > 0

Tags: qt, validation, qml, textinput

I have a few `IntValidator`s inside as many `TextInput`s and they all behave well, except one. The one misbehaving is the only one with its `bottom` property set to something greater than zero. The problem is easily riproducible with the code below (Qt 5.2.0):

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle
{
    id:         mainwindow
    objectName: "mainwindow"
    width:      1024
    height:     768

    TextInput
    {
        id: testtextinput
        objectName: "testtextinput"

        text: "170"
        font.pixelSize: 36

        x: 100
        y: 200
        width: 200
        height: 200

        property size range: Qt.size(160, 180)
        validator: IntValidator
        {
            id:     rangevalidator
            objectName: testtextinput.objectName + "_rangevalidator"

            bottom: testtextinput.range.width
            top:    testtextinput.range.height

            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                console.log("Component.onCompleted objectName: " + objectName + " bottom: " + bottom + " top: " + top)
            }
        }
        onAccepted:
        {
            text = "accepted"
        }
    }
    Text
    {
        id: testisacceptable

        font.pixelSize: 36
        text: testtextinput.acceptableInput

        anchors.top: testtextinput.bottom
        anchors.left: testtextinput.left
        anchors.right: testtextinput.right
        height: 200
    }
}
```

The validator's range is set to [**160**, **180**], so, if I want to type **181**, I can just type **18** and nothing more. However, if I want to type **159**, the **TextInput** allows me to write the whole number, tells me that the number won't be accepted setting to **false** the `acceptableInput` property, but when I press enter, the `onAccepted()` slot is executed without problems. Any ideas on what's happening here? A bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is solved in **Qt 5.3.0** as explained [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-37510).

Comment: That link is not working. Can you explain solution in your answer?

Comment: The link is working, you just have to allow a security exception for the website. And there is not much to explain, it was just a bug that has been fixed in Qt 5.2.1.